# Is this a safe setup to prevent email account hack?

Tags: authentication, email, account-security, multi-factor, attack-prevention

I would like to protect a Gmail account from being hacked.
Suppose I use the following approach for login/authentication:

- Username, Password
- 2FA via security stick
- the stick is in a place that is not accessible to the attacker

Is there a realistic attack to be feared under these conditions?

Comment: What about backup codes? Are they secured in a vault or encrypted?

Comment: Good point. They are secured in a vault.